# Redirect URLs that the website requests to my own URL

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I wonder if I can redirect the JSON, .jpg, .mp3 or any other file URLs that the website requests to my own URL with Greasemonkey?

Example:

If the website requests `https://example.com/example.json`, I want it to be redirected to `https://mywebsite.com/myjson.json`. There are some other file URLs that I want to redirect so I don't want everything to get redirected, just some specific files.

Comment: It depends how the site requests those URLs - how does it make those requests?

Comment: It just does GET on them, there is nothing special. I want it to be redirect so my content can be shown in the website. I will be the only person who can see it.

Comment: `GET` is not a Javascript function - how exactly are those requests made? eg `fetch`? `XMLHttpRequest`? jQuery?

Comment: It is XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a userscript that runs at document-start (before any scripts on the page run) to overwrite `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` with your own method which replaces the second parameter's `example.com` with `mywebsite.com`. Something along the lines of:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Redirect
// @include      /https?://example\.com/
// @run-at       document-start
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

const origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(...args) {
  if (typeof args[1] === 'string') {
    args[1] = args[1].replace('example.com', 'mywebsite.com');
  }
  return origOpen.apply(this, args);
};
```

Comment: Thank you! It works great. Another question, is it possible to redirect everything that gets requested under a domain to somewhere else? Like `https://example.com/*` to `https://mywebsite.com/*`

Comment: Only for resources requested by Javascript, and only by monkeypatching the appropriate methods, whether that's XHR or Fetch, by using the technique in the answer (or something similar to it).

Comment: What about editing the websocket requests/responses?

Comment: You'll need to patch `window.Websocket` to replace with your own URL